# Powershell output is cut by powershell. Dots in output

Tags: powershell

I am facing an issue where output I receive is shortened by '...' dots in PS. I've tried to use Out-String with -Width option. Also Format-Table and such. Those do not work becasue $readable_output is not the string but it is system.object - at least I think that's why it is not giving me the output in full?

That output is provided by the $command which contains specific command from our software (Commvault) and it provides a lot of not required lines and empty lines, so I had to play with that output to only keep the line which is nessecary for me. The example of it prior playing with text output:

```
QScript[GetClientGroup] CS[DGBDFTLV000] DB[CommServ]    Qscript Output:      Client Group  ------------  UX_LINUX_SYST  GetClientGroupcompleted at Sep 15 2020  1:35PM with parameters client   [z85722] or client group []. ErrorCod
e (0).   Qscript Execution Succeeded!
```

So for example the current output of this script is:

```
VM     ClientGroup                      
--     -----------    
z55555 UX_LINUX_PROD
d33222 UX_LINUX_SYST...  # here is the problem, this VM has more than 1 group and it fails to output it.
g71635 UX_DB2_GOLD
```

Script itself:

```
# VM's list
$vms = @("z55555",
"d33222",
"g71635")

# Return VM name and it's client group
function Get-ClientGroup{
$result = @()
    foreach ($vm in $vms){
        $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $object | Add-Member -Name 'VM' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value "$vm"
        $command = qoperation execscript -sn GetClientGroup.sql -si c=$vm 
        $readable_output = $command | Select-String -Pattern "PROD","SYST", "TEST", "GOLD", "CASSANDRA", "50%", "MS", "DB2", "SQL", "Backup" | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-String | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
        $object | Add-Member -Name 'ClientGroup' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value "$readable_output"
        $result += $object
    }
return $result
}
$result = Get-ClientGroup
$result | Out-File -FilePath D:\Scripts\CurrentGroups.txt
```

Comment: Can you use tostring to convert the line containing `UX_LINUX_SYST` to better understand how it appears in the Select-string output

Comment: Actually can you add the output from `$Command` it would help to simulate your situation while I don't have CommVault in my own environment.

Comment: Try using `Out-GridView`. `Format-Table` will automatically cut things off after PowerShell 3 I believe. You may also want to see `Format-List` which doesn't cut off

Comment: If someone is attempting to provide an answer, they really should add it as answer, not a comment.  This allows is to be accepted and for later readers to know there is a potential solution.

Comment: @Steven, $command output is provided in the first script block in the post above.

Although the problem is it cut's off the output not only in the .txt file but as well as in shell itself. So if the VM has more than one client group - I can no longer pass it further on the script because the output from the $readable_output has been already cut and it is not showing all the groups for the VM, only one group following by "...".

Answer (score 4):

Try to pipe it to select-object and expand the property clientgroup:

```
$result | select-object -ExpandProperty ClientGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend either using the `Format-List` option like Neko suggested if you want to keep using TXT files or you can export to a CSV file instead. Powershell tables don't always translate well into text files, but shouldn't cut off data when going into a CSV file.

Comment: Hi @catherinemohan, as I've mentioned in the post - none of the Format- options work, as they change output to the following:
...
`VM     ClientGroup                                                  
--     -----------                                                  
z55555 Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
d33222 Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
g71635 Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData`

Comment: I have never seen `Format-List` produce a table like that. That is specifically against what that command is supposed to do. If it is indeed doing that, you may want to let the Powershell team know about this bug. Since none of the format tools are working for you, I suggest building an output string yourself for each VM and saving those to the text file instead of relying on the `Format` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Examples of expanding truncated output:

```
PS C:\Users\me> curl "http://time.jsontest.com/" | Format-List Content


Content : {
             "date": "04-01-2023",
             "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1680315612532,
             "time": "02:20:12 AM"
          }


PS C:\Users\me> curl "http://time.jsontest.com/" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
{
   "date": "04-01-2023",
   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1680315616004,
   "time": "02:20:16 AM"
}


PS C:\Users\me> curl "http://time.jsontest.com/" | Select-Object Content

Content
-------
{...
```